# Can we specify the number of data generated(minority class) using SMOTE?

Tags: machine-learning, python, class-imbalance, imbalanced-learn

I am trying to improve classification of imbalanced dataset [creditcard fraud](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) using SMOTE [imbalanced_learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn). But, in this it generates the data to 50%, can we give a specific number for the data to be generated? I want to track the classifier performance with the increase in generated data. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

SMOTE is an algorithm for generating as many minority samples as you like. Thus, you can generate as many samples as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the packages such the one in python ([imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)) allows you to set the balancing ratio (which is 1 in the case of 50% minority and 50% majorities).

If you are not using a package without such a ratio parameter, you may use the index of the newly generated samples (if unavailable compare the input to the output and use only the delta) to **find the new samples** and then **randomly chose** the number of new desired samples **only** out of them.